# How to install win XP on external hard disk that connected to windows 7 OS

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, operating-systems, windows-installation

Have one external Hard disk and need to install win XP.
The hard disk is connected through SATA to USB connector in Windows 7

Comment: Boot to Windows XP installation media then choose the HDD you wish to install it too.  Of course you are going to have more problems installing to an external drive.  Unlikely you will even be able to boot to it.

Comment: We need just a little bit more info on what you intend to do, rather than 2 lines

Comment: @Ramhound somebody managed to do it back in the day...https://web.archive.org/web/20091228061152/http://www.ngine.de/index.jsp?pageid=4176

Answer (score -1):

Install [WAIK](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspxhttps://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=5753) (Windows automated Installation Kit). Extract the install.wim file from xp disc image/disc. Follow these [steps](http://www.intowindows.com/how-to-install-windows-7-to-usb-external-hard-drive-must-read/). As WAIK ISO is big (about 1.7GB)  but you just need few files from those almost 1or 2MB. Try finding them on web.

[image: problemwithregularmethod]

Comment: XP install discs did not use wim files.